# Problem with content controls, when creating new document based on template

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a template .dotm file in which I have ActiveX buttons and content controls. The document is unprotected and the editing is enabled.

I've tested creating documents based on this template on multiple computers, running Windows 7/Windows 10 and Office 2010, the document based on template can run the VBA code for the ActiveX objects and the content controls are usable (checkboxes, text fields and date pickers).

However, on a specific computer - Windows 7/Office 2010, when I create a new document based on the template (double-clicking the template), the content controls are no longer being displayed, only the placeholders are displayed simply as text. Also, the checkboxes cannot be used, they are simply characters. However, the ActiveX objects are still working and the VBA code inserted in the template runs.

This problem does not occur when opening the template and working directly on template (Right click - open), but this is not the intended use.

In `Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > ActiveX Settings` and in `Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings` I've selected the most permissive option, allowing all the controls to be run.

I've added the following **scenarios** for a better visualisation of the problem:

**1.** Right Click -> Open (**opening the template**):
[image: opentemplate]

If I enter **Design Mode**:
[image]

As you can see, it's opening with enabled and functioning content controls.

**2.** Double-click on template/Right Click -> New (**new document based on template**):
[image]
For example, the yellow-highlighted should be a textbox content control, but it's a simple text (I had the cursor on it when I took the screenshot).

Entering **Design Mode**:
[image]

As you can see, there are no content controls. The checkboxes are simple characters and there are no textboxes.

On any other computer, creating new document based on the template (as in case 1) work as intended (the document appear as in case 2, with content controls).

Could you guide me in finding out what is causing this problem with the content controls? Thank you!

Comment: What OS & Office version does the affected computer use? Also, are you sure the user isn't saving the document in the older .doc format (which doesn't support content controls)?

Comment: @macropod, it's windows 7 and office 2010. I double click the template and the content controls aren't working, before saving as a specific format. Actually,  as a side note, I know that old .doc doesn't support content controls because this is the way I remove the content controls after they are used for my purpose. In conclusions, creating a new, unsaved, document from the template should not affect the way content controls behave, but I cannot find what's causing the error, as I cannot find a difference between the computers where I've tested the template.

Comment: Do the content controls work if you start Word in safe mode (i.e. depress the Ctrl key while starting Word)? If so a rogue 3rd-party addin is the likely culprit.

Comment: @CindyMeister, the issue was that every document as opening in Compatibility Mode for Office 2003. As a workaround, I've changed in `File`->`Options`->`Save`->`Save files in this format` from `Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)` to `Word Document (*.docx)`.

Comment: For some reason, I wasn't seeing your comments - Sorry! Didn't want to leave you hanging... but I probably wouldn't have thought of what you eventually found! It would be good for the site for you to write up what you found in an Answer as this could help others. Try sending me a comment, again, when you have and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple test at different computers, I have noticed that the problem occurs only on those that have Compatibility Mode enabled. At these computers, every new document was opening in Compatibility Mode for Office 2003, even though the templated was saved as .dotm.

In order to disable this compatibility mode, I've changed in `File`->`Options`->`Save`->`Save files in this format` from `Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)` to `Word Document (*.docx)`.